# connect a device automatically without configuring at iot platform end

Tags: mqtt, open-source

My main goal is to connect devices but only with an access token and not by manually adding devices to the cloud IoT platform
Is there a platform to do that automatically? How to do it/Which platform is good for that purpose?

why I asked this question?: I have used Node-RED, thinger.io, and thingspeak. However, in most of them, we should add device manually and make a device auth token is it possible to add a device automatically and subscribe to a topic(topic name is the same one) and  get data without manually adding devices Basically, I need an automatic device registry either based on tokens or using username and password login.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the big (e.g. IBM, AWS, Azure) IoT platforms support automated device enrolment.

IBM Watson IoT:
https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/device-identity-provisioning-with-wisekeys-managed-pki-api/

AWS IoT:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/iot/setting-up-just-in-time-provisioning-with-aws-iot-core/

Azure IoT Hub:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/concepts-auto-provisioning

Comment: @hardillb what about an open source  iot platform that I can delploy in my own server ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of

Answer (score 3):

You can use [uBeac IoT platform](https://www.ubeac.io/?utm_source=iot.stackexchange.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=4108).

You should create a gateway and it will give you a unique URL (which you can change it later). Then, set the given URL in your device.

You can configure the security options as below:

- HTTP/HTTPS with or without additional security header
- MQTT with or without credentials

For debugging purpose, you can send data without any security settings.

Comment: every device should have same url? how will the ubec seperate devices that have same MQTT channels (for example) , Suppose i have 10 lamps and i have same MQTT channels on each lamp and when connecting to the ubec platform will it register 10 devices and show each devices it unique names and with its own mqtt channel?

Comment: @Amrith Yes, if you are publishing the data, it will define 10 devices with unique names. We do not support MQTT subscribing in this version.